# Semantic Multiple Modals On Same Page

Tags: semantic-ui

Is it possible to have multiple modals attached to seperate buttons on the same page?  I am having problems that when I click one of the buttons both modals are popping up.  These modal have forms in them, that is why I have them set to not closable.

**MAIN HTML CODE:**

```
<table class="ui violet compact celled table">
.
.
.
<tfoot class="full-width">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
            <div class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon billboard button">
                <i class="plus icon"></i> Add Slide
            </div>
            <div class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon button">
                <i class="minus icon"></i> Delete Slide(s)
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>

<table class="ui violet compact celled table">
.
.
.
<tfoot class="full-width">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">
            <div class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon campaign button">
                <i class="plus icon"></i> Add Slide
            </div>
            <div class="ui right floated small primary labeled icon button">
                <i class="minus icon"></i> Delete Slide(s)
            </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

**MODAL HTML:**

```
<div class="ui standard billboard modal" style="margin-top: -197.5px; display: block !important;">
.
.
.
</div>

<div class="ui standard campaign modal" style="margin-top: -197.5px; display: block !important;">
.
.
.
</div>
```

**MODAL JS:**

```
$('.billboard.modal')
        .modal({
            closable  : false
        })
        .modal('attach events', '.billboard.button', 'show')
;

$('.campaign.modal')
        .modal({
            closable  : false
        })
        .modal('attach events', '.campaign.button', 'show')
;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found an answer.  In the class for the modal I just added 'transition hidden' and that seems to solve the problem.